# How to pass the php parameter in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

From Here I am doing like I fetch data from database and display in table format still it is working fine, after I click the `division_edit()` function I want pass the value (`id`),how can do this.

```html
<table id="dataTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S.No</th>
      <th>Division</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php $sql=m ysql_query( "SELECT * FROM division WHERE status !='1'"); for($i=1;$row=m ysql_fetch_assoc($sql);$i++){ ?>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>
        <?php echo $i;?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row[ 'division'];?>
      </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="state_edit.php?id=<?php echo base64_encode($row['id']);?>" onclick="division_edit()" id="division_edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit</a> 
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-href="state_delete.php?id=<?php echo base64_encode($row['id']);?>"
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>S.No</th>
      <th>Division</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: `onclick="division_edit(<?php echo base64_encode($row['id']);?>)"`

Answer (score 0):

May this help you:

```
<table id="dataTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>S.No</th>
      <th>Division</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php $sql=m ysql_query( "SELECT * FROM division WHERE status !='1'"); for($i=1;$row=m ysql_fetch_assoc($sql);$i++){ ?>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td>
        <?php echo $i;?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $row[ 'division'];?>
      </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="state_edit.php?id=<?php echo base64_encode($row['id']);?>" onclick="division_edit(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>)" id="division_edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit</a> 
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-href="state_delete.php?id=<?php echo base64_encode($row['id']);?>"
        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>

  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>S.No</th>
      <th>Division</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="state_edit.php?id=<?php echo base64_encode($row['id']);?>" onclick="division_edit(<?php echo $row['id'] ?>)" id="division_edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Edit</a>
```

Comment: Oh WoW! You beautified my answer. Thanks Men

Comment: Thanks,But how to use this function base64_encode()

Comment: How to pass two parameter